# vbscript doesn't work on hta

Tags: vbscript, hta

please help i am trying to display a message on another computer on our network we can not use net send since doesn't exist on windows 7 and we can not use MSG because is disable, and GPO will disable it if we enable it. so i have a vbscript on the user's computer that display the message, and another vbscript that sends the message to be display. when i use this code to send the message as a regular vbscript it works

```
Dim strMessage, strComputer, strLocalPath, strFile, objShell 
Dim strRemotePath, objShellApp, strTest, sPSEXEC
strComputer = InputBox("enter computer Name", "create File")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & 
strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colComputer = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
currentpath = objShell.CurrentDirectory & "\"
sPSEXEC = currentPath & "psexec.exe"
strFile = """c:\windows\notification.vbs"""
strMessage = InputBox("enter Message", "create File")
strTest = "\\"&strComputer&" " &"cscript.exe"&" "&strFile&" 
"&"/message:"&Chr(34)&strMessage&Chr(34)
WScript.Echo strTest
objShellApp.ShellExecute "cmd.exe","/k "&sPSEXEC&" -s -i -d "&" "&strTest, "","runas",1
```

but put the same code on hta it try to open the script on the user computer but it dies before it can display the message

```
<script Language = VBScript>
On Error Resume Next
Sub WindowsLoad
Dim strMessage, strComputer, strLocalPath, strFile, objShell
Dim strRemotePath, objShellApp, strTest, sPSEXEC    
strComputer = computerName.Value
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & 
_strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colComputer = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShellAPP = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
currentpath = objShell.CurrentDirectory & "\"
sPSEXEC = currentPath & "psexec.exe"
strFile = """c:\windows\notification.vbs"""
strTest = "\\"&strComputer&" " &"cscript.exe"&" "&strFile&"   
_"&"/message:"&Chr(34)&strMessage&Chr(34)
objShellApp.ShellExecute "cmd.exe","/k "&sPSEXEC&" -s -i -d "&" "&strTest, "", 
_"runas", 1
End Sub
</script>
<Body>
<div>
</div>

Computer Name: <Input align="right" Type = "Text" Name = "computerName">
</br>
</br>
Message: 
</br>
<TEXTAREA NAME="Message" COLS=30 ROWS=6>

</TEXTAREA>
</br>
</br>
<Input Type = "Button" Value = "Send Message" Name = "Run_Button" onClick = "WindowsLoad"><P>
```

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: a global `On Error Resume Next` is the root of all evil. Do **not** use this unless you know *exactly* what you're doing and how to handle any error that may occur.

That said, your script probably dies, because the VBScript code in the HTA is invalid. If you want to use line continuation, the underscore **must** be at the **end** of the line you want to continue, not at the **beginning** of the continued line:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & 
_strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

Also you cannot use line continuation **inside** a string:

```
strTest = "\\"&strComputer&" " &"cscript.exe"&" "&strFile&"   
_"&"/message:"&Chr(34)&strMessage&Chr(34)
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion I removed the on error resume next, and the line continuations on both places, but the script still doing the same.

Comment: Your HTA has line continuations in 3 places. If you still get an error after you fixed that, please update your question with the corrected code and the actual error message.

Comment: i am sorry had not being able to answered back, but yes i removed all the line continuations, the problem is that i do not get any type of error it just open the cmd and shows the script part on the tool bar for few second and then it dies thanks

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I asked you to update your question with the corrected HTA code, i.e. the code you are using *now*.